# CUDA dijkstra's algorithm

Tags: algorithm, cuda, dijkstra

Has anybody implemented a CUDA parallelization version of Dijkstra's Algorithm for a given sparse matrix (cuSPARSE) graph, and for source, and target node, find the minimal K path?

I really need it to solve a general graph I'll be constructing.

Vincent

Comment: `1.` Are you talking about using multiple threads to find the shortest path in a single graph, or finding a single path per thread over many graphs?  The former is likely(?) very difficult, but the latter should be fairly easy... though, due to the way CUDA GPUs work *(all threads in a half-warp assume the same conditionals, nearby memory accesses etc.)*, you might not get the performance increase you hope. `2.` When you say 'minimal k path', are you really talking about solving the [K-shortest paths problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K_shortest_path_routing)?

Comment: You will probably also be interested in [this](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpu-ai-path-finding) and [this](http://www.graphicshardware.org/presentations/bleiweiss-GPU_accelerated_pathfinding.pdf)

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/13576/2061

Comment: Hi,
Yes I mean Yen's K-shortest path problem. Is there any CUDA functions that do pathfinding given a graph G and a source id/target id node?