# CUDA dijkstra's shortest path from source to target

Tags: cuda, dijkstra, shortest-path

I have been trying to find a function that uses CUDA which is able to find the shortest path for positive-weight directed graph (much like Dijkstra's algorithm).

Can someone lead me to the right people or kernels/algorithm already made for solving the shortest path?

Comment: Is this the same question as [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15099054/cuda-dijkstras-algorithm)?

Comment: If you have broad, difficult to directly answer questions like this, please ask them on the [NVIDIA forums](http://devtalk.nvidia.com).